# Bill having rejected his job offer. what grammatical point is it?

Tags: grammar

I ran into this question in an exam and could not figure out which option to choose and why!
In its key, choice 2 is selected as the correct answer.

> 4- Mr. Hill decided to offer the position to Henry, ………….. .
>     1) having rejected his job offer by Bill
>     2) Bill having rejected his job offer
>     3) Bill rejecting his job offer
>     4) being rejected his job offer by Bill

why not choice 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Choice 1 is an example of a [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier). The clause *having rejected his job offer by Bill* is a modifying clause in which the verb *having rejected* is actually associated with the subject of the sentence, *Mr. Hill*, rather than with *Bill* as intended.

In choice 2, *having rejected* is correctly associated with *Bill*, as intended.

Answer (score 0):

All four options are stilted and awkward.  At least *Option 2* is a phrase containing a subject. *Option 1* is ambiguous concerning who does the rejection.   I would opt for:

*Mr. Hill decided to offer the position to Henry, after Bill rejected the offer.*